# How to detect the compression level of a JPEG image?

Tags: php, image, jpeg

Would it be possible to detect the compression level of a JPEG image using PHP, without having the "original" (uncompressed) version of the file?

If yes, how to do it?

Comment: I think you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853851/libjpeg-get-compression-ratio-of-image

Comment: If you just want to know the compression ratio of the file sizes as such you need to know the format of the original. So an original 24 bit RGB would be of size 3*width*height bytes and now you have the current jpeg size and you would get the compression ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes PHP Imagick can do this for you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getcompression.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getcompressionquality.php

Comment: That isn't the same as quality .. (note that JPEG is a compression type)

Comment: As for the 2nd link, I wonder how it works in practice. AFAIK the compression quality is not stored as part of the JPEG header/meta-information ..

Comment: @pst I am not really sure to be honest.  I use Imagick fairly frequently but not those methods.

Comment: I must say I'm confused. What I know as the "compression level" for the JPEG algorithm is an integer ranging from 0 to 100 (100 = no compression, from what I know) that you also encounter in software like Corel Draw or Photoshop when exporting to JPEG.