# Saving an image file after adding a text

Tags: c#, image, gdi+

I wrote a piece of code to open an image file (JPEG), adding some text to it and saving it to a different file.

It looks like this:

```
Image sourceImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(sourceImage);
grp.DrawString(...);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sourceImage);
bmp.Save(newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This works just fine, and the file is saved successfully with the text added to it.

However, the original file is about 1.5MB, and the new file is about 480KB only. When I look at the details of each file I can see that the dimensions are similar, but the original file has 180 dpi resolution and the new one has 96. The original image also has Color representation (sRGB) and Compressed bits/pixel (4), while the new image doesn't hold these details.

Can these be the cause for the difference in the file size?

Can anyone think of a way I can save the new file with the exact size, and not a file which is more compact?

Many thanks,

Elad

Comment: I don't think the original Image is a JPEG file. You can try opening it with notepad and see if there is some string JPEG at the very beginning of the whole text content. I guess it's a BMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JPEG compression level when saving the image. See [Quality of a saved JPG in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484759/quality-of-a-saved-jpg-in-c-sharp).

However, it [seems to be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853851/libjpeg-get-compression-ratio-of-image) to find out with which quality settings a JPEG has been saved, so I don't think you can save your own JPEG with the same compression level as the input JPEG.